# Unable to send an email using php codeigniter 3.3 on test env

Tags: php, email

```
public function sendEmail()
    {
        // Enable CORS headers
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, ApiKey");

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
            exit();
        }

        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ($method != 'POST') {
            $response = array('status' => 400, 'message' => 'Bad request.');
        } else {
            $check_auth_client = $this->MyModel->check_auth_client();
            if ($check_auth_client) {
                // Get payload data
                $receiver_email = isset($_POST['receiver_email']) ? $_POST['receiver_email'] : '';
                $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
                $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

                if (empty($receiver_email) || empty($username) || empty($password)) {
                    $response = array('status' => 400, 'message' => 'Missing required parameters.');
                } else {
                    // Extract payload data
                    $subject = 'Welcome to Smart Mobile Finance';

                    $this->load->library('email');
                    $config = $this->config->item('email_settings');

                    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

                    $this->email->initialize($config);
                    $this->email->from($config['default_email_from'], 'SmartMobileFinance');
                    $this->email->to($receiver_email);
                    $this->email->subject($subject);
                    $this->email->message('Your Smart Mobile Finance Credentials are:<br><br>' .

                        'Username: ' . $username . '<br>' .
                        'Password: ' . $password . '<br><br>' .

                        'Thanks,<br>' .
                        'Smart Mobile Finance Team');

                    // Send email
                    if ($this->email->send()) {
                        $response = array('status' => 200, 'message' => 'Email sent successfully.');
                    } else {
                        $response = array('status' => 400, 'message' => 'Failed to send email: ' . $this->email->print_debugger());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $response = array('status' => 401, 'message' => 'Unauthorized access. API key is required.');
            }
        }
        $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output(json_encode($response));
    }
```

```
$config['email_settings']['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['email_settings']['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['email_settings']['smtp_user'] = '*****************';
$config['email_settings']['smtp_pass'] = '**************';
$config['email_settings']['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['email_settings']['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['email_settings']['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['email_settings']['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['email_settings']['smtp_crypto'] = "tls";
$config['email_settings']['default_email_from'] = '***********';
```

when i using this api function into postamn then i am able to send an email on local host while when i am sending an email using test env then i will get an error

{
"status": 400,
"message": "Failed to send email: The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method."
}

when i using this api function into postamn then i am able to send an email on local host while when i am sending an email using test env then i will get an error

{
"status": 400,
"message": "Failed to send email: The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method."
}

i am trying to sending an email using different env but on local host i am able to sending email but failed to sending on test env and getting an error]

Comment: *110 Connection timed out* looks like network issues

Comment: what to do in that case becuase when i run this using postman i don't get this but when i use this api into react project then i get this issue

Comment: _"i am able to send an email on local host while when i am sending an email using test env then i will get an error"_ - What's the difference between "local host" and "test env"? Those aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. You then say "when I use this into react project" which isn't mutually exclusive to anything here either. Explain the differences please. Are they running on different servers? When it doesn't work, is that on some hosting company (which sometimes block third party mail services and require customers to go through their smtp instead)?

Comment: yes they both are on different servers because on localhost it is used an apache server while on test env we are using aws.